# Create recurring dates on every first Sunday of month

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using the [moment-recur](https://github.com/c-trimm/moment-recur) library iam trying to generate dates for every first sunday of the month

Below is my code

```
var myDate, recurrence;

// Create a date to start from
myDate = moment("05/01/2016");
recurrence = myDate.recur().every("Sunday").daysOfMonth();

//recurrence = myDate.recur().every([3, 5]).days();

for(i=0;i<100;i++){
  dt1=moment(myDate).add(i,'days');
  check=recurrence.matches(dt1);
  if(check){
    document.writeln(' <p>' + moment(dt1).format('dddd, DD-MMM-YYYY'));

  }else{
     //document.write('date not matching');
  }

}
```

this code not working, here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MydZML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved it myself,
Edited Recurrence rule as this,

```
recurrence = myDate.recur().every("Sunday").daysOfWeek().every([0]).weeksOfMonthByDay();
```

now it matches on every first sunday of the months, i hope it will help some other